# How to refer to a cell value within importrange function?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am using this formula to bring data from another spreadsheet file based on name of the month. This time for February..

`=query(importrange("1L86iP0GLHTubwfvxs1kJ4ocbmgRAd4Iz0000000M","'February'!A2:F"),"Select Col6, Col5 where Col1 is not null",0)`

But I would like to type the cell that has the month name instead of writing the month manually in each formula. If the cell C1="February" in file A and C1="January" in file B, how can I write C1 instead of month name in the formula? for example like this:

`=query(importrange("1L86iP0GLHTubwfvxs1kJ4ocbmgRAd4Iz000000jbcM","'C1'!A2:F"),"Select Col6, Col5 where Col1 is not null",0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your formula, `February`  or `January`  **must be** tab names belonging to the spreadsheet.

**If that is the case**, use the following syntax

```
=query(importrange("1L86iP0GLHTubwfvxs1kJ4ocbmgRAd4Iz0000000M", C1&"!A2:F"),"Select Col6, Col5 where Col1 is not null",0)
```

where cell `C1` has a value of `February`  or `January`  or...

*(If still in trouble please explain better or share a test sheet.)*

Comment: Yes February and January are Tabs.. It worked thanks alot

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept.